# Выводит неправильные числа при использовании типа va_list

Tags: c

Есть процедура:

```
void    func(char *str, ...)
{
    va_list             ap;
    long long signed    number;

    va_start(ap, str);
    number = va_arg(ap, long long);
    printf("number = %lld\n", number);
}
```

Вызов: `func("42", -42);`

Вывод: `number = 4294967254`

Вопрос: Почему -42 превращается в 4294967254?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что вы передаете `-42`, которое является ни чем иным, как `int`. А обрабатываете его как `long long`...

Передайте `long long`: `func("42", -42ll);` - и [все у вас получится](https://ideone.com/tj7Fse) :)

Comment: Благодарю. А почему это так работает? long long ведь всё равно целочисленный тип даных.

Comment: А размер у него отличается от размера `int`... Тут же важен размер - где в стеке он располагается, и сколько байт занимает. Вместо 4 байт, в которых хранится -42, ваш код выводит содержимое 8 байт..

Comment: @Laughing_Man: Аргументы, соответствующие `...`, условно говоря, передаются как *бинарный* поток данных. Правильно разобрать этот бинарный поток при помощи `va_arg` - ваша задача. Если вы скажете `va_arg` читать `long long`, в то время как в потоке сидит `int` - получится ерунда уже хотя бы потому, что размеры типов не совпадают. В реальности реализация может отличаться и эти аргументы совсем не обязательно располагаются в некоем "стеке", но эффект все равно может быть тем же.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно `Стандарту языка C`, тип литерала определяется по его значению.

Точное описание этого процесса представлено в **§6.4.4.1**, из которого следует следующее:

Самым *младшим* возможным типом числового литерала является тип `int`. Если не указано специальных префиксов и суффиксов, а так же если значение целочисленного литерала умещается в тип `int`, то тип литерала - `int`.

Следовательно, ваш вызов:

```
func("42", -42);
```

Размещает в стеке значение типа `int`. Поскольку в вашей системе размерности `int` и `long long int` не совпадают, вы получаете некорректный результат.

Comment: Если уж быть предельно педантичным, то в терминологии языка С `42` - это не "литерал", а целочисленная *константа*. В С есть только строковые литералы и составные литералы.

Comment: Также, ради еще пущей педантичности можно заметить, что `-42` - это константное *выражение*, (а не константа и не литерал). Разумеется, тип этого выражения совпадает с типом *константы* `42`.

Comment: Нет. Единой терминологии нет, а терминология языка С сложилась давно, когда необходимость в единой терминологии была не так насущна. В языке С после `const int i = 1;`, `i` - это НЕ константа, а "неизменяемая переменная". Вы не сможете использовать такое `i` там, где языком требуется константное выражение (например, метка `case`, ширина bit-field или размер не-VLA массива). *Константами* в терминологии языка С называются: буквальные значения (вроде `1`, `3.5` и `'c'`), члены enum, результаты `sizeof` и `_Alignof` времени компиляции. Такова терминология языка С.

Comment: Все вас поймут правильно, если вы будете в языке С назвать константы *литералами*. Я сам обеими руками "за". Но, еще раз, с занудно-придирчивой педантичной точки зрения формальной терминологии языка С это не верно. Использование термина "литерал" в этой роли - это терминология языка С++, но не языка С.

Comment: Использование термина "константа" в отношении `const int i = 1;` в языке С - это источник большого количества часто задаваемых вопросов от новичков, которые вдруг удивляются, когда компилятор отказывается принимать такое `i` в качестве *константы*, указывая в сообщении об ошибке, что "здесь требуется константа, а ваше `i` - не константа".

Comment: @AnT, спасибо за детальное объяснение. Это действительно сложная и тонкая тема, которая находится на стыке лингвистики, информатики и исторически сложившихся технических особенностей стандарта языка программирования.